# The Delta for Patch is null

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here are my Entities.  I am using entity framework code first.

```
public class Trade
    {

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string AssetClass { get; set; }
        public TradeBatch Batch { get; set; }
    }

public class TradeBatch
    {
        public TradeBatch()
        {
            StartedOn = DateTime.Now;

        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartedOn { get; set; }


        public List<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
    }
```

In My Controller I have:

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
public void UpdateTrade(Guid id, Delta<Trade> update)
{
    var tradeToUpdate = _repTradeService.GetRepTradeById(id);
    update.Patch(tradeToUpdate);
    _repTradeService.SaveChanges();
 }
```

When I Make a request (using fiddler), update is null.
Here is the patch Request:

```
PATCH http://localhost:61579/api/RepTrades/4e43b48a-a4fd-4ffc-841d-08dac55deb60 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:61579
Content-Length: 55

Content-Type: application/json
{"AssetClass":"Test"}
```

The value for "Update" in the Patch Action is always null. Any pointers to why?

Comment: I just threw a few frustrating hours away on this today, and in my case the problem turned out to be that my model class did not have a parameterless constructor.  I'm not sure if you had a similar issue, but hopefully this will save someone some time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try setting the content-type header to `application/json;odata=verbose`

I would have just commented but don't have the reputation yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is fine, and the method should accept it as far as I can see. You can see what the exact error is by adding the following line of code at the top of your `PATCH` method:

```cs
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,  ModelState));
}
```

This way, if your JSON is not valid according to the model the method is expecting, it returns a `HTTP 400 Bad Request` message, along with the ModelState. The message of that response will contain the reason why the ModelState is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer from @kazu helped me find the problem because it gave me a break point where the debugger could reveal the problem.

I had a setter in my class, which was trying to set a property on an object which had not been initialised. By breaking with the debugger on the "throw" command, I was able to see the stack trace in the properties of the ModelState object, and the stacktrace said my setter on a particular field was throwing "Object Reference Not Set". With that I could immediately see the problem.

My object was like this:

```
public MyObject
{
    private PrivateObjectType _privateObject;

    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    public string myProperty
    {
       get { return _privateObject.myProperty; }
       set { _privateObject.myProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

So obviously I needed to put this in the constructor:

```
_privateObject = new PrivateObjectType();
```